# pytest mocker.patch not working for Vault

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am new to pytest and unittesting and having an issue below (fake and simplied version of code):

## app.py

```
from vault import Vault

vault = Vault(role_id, secret_id)

def function_to_be_tested():
    pass
```

## **test_app.py**

```
from app import function_to_be_tested

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_vault(mocker):
    mock_vault = mocker.patch('app.Vault', autospec=True)
    mock_vault.return_value = None
    return mock_vault


def test_function():
    pass
```

I want to mock the Vault instance in my all tests. However, in the collection phase of pytest, it still tries to connect to Vault.

AFAIK, the `Vault` instance in `app.py` is being created at the module level, so it's being instantiated as soon as I import `app.py`, which is before the pytest fixtures get a chance to mock it.